# Why does removing the cut operator in this Prolog recursion not matter?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, prolog, trace

Regardless of whether I use cut operators or not in the following code, I receive the same answer of Y = 2.

```
%% Operation 1
f([H|T], Y) :- 
    f(H, A),
    f(T, B),
    Y is A + B,
    !.

%% Operation 2
f(c, 1) :- 
    !.

%% Operation 3
f(_, 0).
```

When I run the query `f([c, [c], d], Y).` and trace, I see the same steps are taken. I tried to remove the cut operator (`!`) from Operation 2 and saw no difference. After removing this, I also removed the cut operator from Operation 1 and saw no difference either. Why does using the cut operator not matter here? ([Link to run code](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/find-path.pl))

Comment: This is a very loaded question. What are you trying to cut and why? What did you expect to see with or without the cuts, and why?

Comment: Hint: you are recursing into the same predicate _before_ you cut.

Comment: The SWISH link goes to some other example program, please edit the question to add the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

Your query `f([c, [c], d], Y).` first unifies with rule 1 and succeeds with `Y = 2`. But the last goal of that rule is a cut that commits to this derivation path (i.e. it prevents backtracking), leaving you with only that solution. You can find the missing answers by removing the cut in rule 1.

A minimal example of this phenomenon looks like this:

```
g(1) :-
  !.
g(2).
```

The general query now has only one answer even though there are two:

```
?- g(X).
X = 1.

?- g(1).
true.

?- g(2).
true.
```

In other words, cut undermines the logical foundation of Prolog because the rule of generalisation ( P(t) → ∃x P(x) i.e. a predicate holds for an instance means it also holds for the predicate where the term is replace by a variable) does not hold anymore.

Comment: *... gives that instance as an answer substitution.* Consider `p(_).`  So `p(1).` holds. Yet, `p(X)` does not produce `X = 1.`, as you suggest.

Comment: Hm, yes... the witness does not need to be ground. Not sure if the new formulation is more precise though.

Comment: Counterexample to new formulation: `q([_]).` So `q([1]).` holds. Yet, `p(X)` does not produce `X = [1]`. Actually, the answer substitution itself has that ground query as an instance.

Comment: Wouldn't my explanation just say: `q([1])` succeeds, so also `q([X])` succeeds. There's no mention of the answer substitution anymore.

Comment: Indeed, but to insist on the notion of answer (where answer substitution is a special case primarily of relevance to syntactic unification) is insightful..